# Rails 4.2: image paths have no fingerprint in production, Capistrano deployment

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, capistrano3

In development my all of my images, CSS and JS are loading fine. In production, my CSS and JS are loading fine. Background images load fine through CSS, and images written as:

```
image_tag "foo.png"
```

also load fine and show a fingerprint. However, images written as:

```
image_tag @test_question.question.image
```

are not fingerprinted in production (the image name is recorded in the database). However, this works fine in development.

In development I see:

```
<img src="/assets/picture1-a2bac24ba737cf267b5cc29f9fdaea33.jpg">
```

In production I see:

```
<img src="/images/picture1.jpg">
```

Assets including the images are compiled and fingerprinted in appropriate directories on my production server, they are just not fingerprinted or called correctly in the view. I am using Rails 4.2, nginx and unicorn, and deploying with Capistrano 3.2.

### Edit:

I have image subdirectories. The following is in my initializers:

initializers/assets.rb

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << path
end
```

When I comment this out, the behaviour is the same in development as in production. So, I suppose that the problem is that this code is not working / being read in the production environment. Any suggestions?

---

environments/production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Date.new.to_s)
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

deploy.rb

```
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'foobar'
set :deploy_user, 'deploy'
# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }.call

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:deploy_user)}/apps/#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:foobar/baz.git'

set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.2'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}

set :keep_releases, 2

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/application.yml}

set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for :format is :pretty
set :format, :pretty

# what specs should be run before deployment is allowed to
# continue, see lib/capistrano/tasks/run_tests.cap
set :tests, []

# which config files should be copied by deploy:setup_config
# see documentation in lib/capistrano/tasks/setup_config.cap
# for details of operations
set(:config_files, %w(
  nginx.conf
  log_rotation
  monit
  unicorn.rb
  unicorn_init.sh
  application.yml
  database.yml
))

# which config files should be made executable after copying
# by deploy:setup_config
set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# files which need to be symlinked to other parts of the
# filesystem. For example nginx virtualhosts, log rotation
# init scripts etc.

set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "log_rotation",
    link: "/etc/logrotate.d/{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "monit",
    link: "/etc/monit/conf.d/{{full_app_name}}.conf"
  }
])

namespace :deploy do

  before :deploy, "deploy:check_revision"

  # compile assets locally then rsync
    #after 'deploy:symlink:shared', 'deploy:compile_assets_locally'
  #after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
  # remove the default nginx configuration as it will tend
  # to conflict with our configs.
    before 'deploy:setup_config', 'nginx:remove_default_vhost'
  # reload nginx to it will pick up any modified vhosts from
  # setup_config
    after 'deploy:setup_config', 'nginx:reload'
  # Restart monit so it will pick up any monit configurations
  # we've added
    after 'deploy:setup_config', 'monit:restart'
  # As of Capistrano 3.1, the `deploy:restart` task is not called
  # automatically.
    after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'

    after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
end
```

I really can't see what the problem is here. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the difference between your *environments/development.rb* and *environments/production.rb*?

Comment: development.rb (opposite boolean in production.rb): cache_classes = true; eager_load = false; consider_all_requests_local = true; action_controller.perform_caching = false;   production.rb also the following, which are not in development.rb:  config.assets.compile = false; config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true

Comment: should be all fine in that way, to configure files have md5 in their names controlled only by *config.assets.digest*